# How to handle empty files in BizTalk Custom File Adapter?

Tags: file, adapter, biztalk

I'm trying to create a custom File adapter for BizTalk 2016 with a few settings to be able to handle 0-byte files since the basic File adapter just gobbles them up. I figured first step would be to build the adapter in the SDK and then add features to it.

But it doesn't work. I get errors, it can't remove the file because it is used by another process.

Below is the BizTalk error

[image: BizTalk error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process]

Renamed file in Explorer
[image: Renamed file]

Output in DebugView
[image: Debugview]

This is not fun since I have not changed a single byte in the code, I expected it to run without any problems. So I started to look around and found first [Ninos Blog](http://ninocrudele.com/biztalk-and-zero-byte-file) where he modifies the adapter from the SDK so it writes 0-byte files simply by writing a size 0 bytearray to the stream. But since my SDK adapter does not work that would not work either.

And then I found [Sandros Github](https://github.com/sandroasp/BizTalk-Server-Resources/tree/master/Adapters/BTS2020) and his "File-Z Adapter" which work when I deploy it since it has a different way of creating messages, and it uses the same trick as Nino did, it writes a 0-size bytearray to the stream.

```
if (fs.Length == 0)
   fs.Write(new byte[0], 0, 0);
```

But if I remove that two lines of code it STILL outputs a 0-byte file.

So I'm stuck at the moment.

1. The SDK-adapter should work but I can't figure out why it doesn't.
2. Remove the 0-size bytearray from Sandros code should stop it from writing 0-byte files but it doesn't.

I've created my own custom adapter with a propertie "Write Zero-byte Files" which I want to use to switch on/off the writing of 0-byte files. But I can't at the moment.

How can I get the SDK-adapter to work?
How can I get Sandros adapter to not output 0-byte files?

Comment: Why do you even want to process a zero byte file?   Also you seem to be talking about 2 issues 1) Receiving 0 byte files and 2) sending 0 byte files.  Tip: A quick workaround for receiving 0 byte files is to use the FTP adapter instead.

Comment: Receiving 0-byte files are ok.

At my work we often handle empty files (0-byte), say a system is supposed to send us a file EVERY day of something, regardless if it is empty or not. If we don't get a file in a certain time-window an error is raised. We didn't get a file!
Then we send this file on to another system which has the same kind of alarm, they expect a file EVERY day.

With the current File-adapter it just gobbles the empty file up and we don't have anything to send, the company with the receiving system calls us and asks why they didn't get a file?

Comment: We also has som other feature we like to add to this custom adapter. So I very much would like to get it to work.

Why doesn't the sample code from the SDK work? It is untouched.. I expect Microsoft to supply working code.

Comment: Can you let us know what version of BizTalk?

Comment: Also you haven't clarified which is the problem you want to solve?  In one instance you are talking about wanting to pick up 0-byte files, but then you start talking about not wanting to output 0-byte files?  If it is picked up, it has to go somewhere or you to have something to discard it.

Comment: Edited question with BizTalkversion (2016).

I have one problem only, I want to be able to switch on/off the writing of 0-byte files.

The standard Fileadapter picks up 0-byte files but does not create a message to the messagebox.

The Fileadapter in the SDK doesn't work so I can't use Ninos way of solving this problem.

Sandros Adapter outputs 0-byte files but I can't make it to NOT do that.

This code in Sandros adapter in the method CreateMessage() should do the trick but doesn't:

if (fs.Length == 0 && this.properties.WriteZeroByteFiles)
{
   fs.Write(new byte[0], 0, 0);
}

Comment: If you don't want to output a file, you want something a NULL or void adapter, e.g. see https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2022/01/31/biztalk-server-void-adapter/  see how it is done there and make it a configurable option

Comment: Yes I have looked at that adapter but that is a send adapter that voids all outgoing messages. One solution would be to tag all incoming messages with something if we don't want them written and then filter when sending them, but this makes us dependant on one more component and running the risk of setting up the filtering wrong. I have not found a way of filtering on filesize out of the box.

Comment: What I want is a Adater with a propertie that I can set for creating/not creating 0-byte files when they are received.